# Overlay Color caroussel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with owl caroussel, i tried in many ways to remove the overlay but not working, ***i want to keep the original colors of picture***, can someone help me to find a solution ?

I'm a beginner with use of caroussel. I can't find where i have to change this setting.

You can see the caroussel of my template.

```
    <section class="banner-section banner-one banner-one-page" id="home">

        <div class="banner-carousel owl-theme owl-carousel">
            <!-- Slide Item -->
            <div class="slide-item">
                <div class="image-layer" style="background-image: url(images/main-slider/2.jpg);"></div>

                <div class="auto-container">
                    <div class="content-box">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="inner text-center">
                                <div class="sub-title">welcome to Linoor agency</div>
                                <h1>Discover <br> <span>new linoor agency</span></h1>
                                <div class="link-box">
                                    <a class="theme-btn btn-style-one" href="about.html">
                                        <i class="btn-curve"></i>
                                        <span class="btn-title">Discover More</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="vid-link">
                                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Get7rqXYrbQ"
                                            class="lightbox-image">
                                            <div class="icon"><span class="flaticon-play-button-1"></span><i
                                                    class="ripple"></i></div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here you can see all files in JS,CSS folder : https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfyMC.jpg

Here you can see the template : http://layerdrops.com/linoor/one-page.html

Comment: Do you mean the white 'flash' that is happening in between slides? If possible could you please edit your question and add the CSS as well as HTML. Thanks Anthony.

Comment: Sorry i edit my message, i want to remove overlay to keep original colors of the picture.

Answer (score 2):

Any carousel item has an `before` pseudo-element with this styles:

```
.banner-carousel .slide-item:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--thm-black);
    opacity: 0.6;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

if you add in your css file the style `.banner-carousel .slide-item:before { display: none; }`, you will remove the translucent black overlay.

Comment: Oh it was simple ! Thanks for your help, i thought it looks like to greyscale settings, but not. Thanks you so much !